# C++: Callback typedefs with __stdcall in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typedef

This typedef:

```
typedef DWORD WINAPI
(* CM_Open_DevNode_Key)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PHKEY, DWORD);
```

compiles fine in BorlandCpp, however, when I compile it in msvc I have to remove `WINAPI` (which is just an alias for `__stdcall`):

```
typedef DWORD
(* CM_Open_DevNode_Key)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PHKEY, DWORD);
```

Why is this happening? Can I remove the WINAPI part safely?

**Update**: I had to remove "WINAPI" form the typedef, otherwise I got

```
 error C2059: syntax error : '('
```

for the line.

*Can you tell me why Borland could compile it with "WINAPI" while Msvc couldn't?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe on VC++ you need to put the calling convention inside the ()'s  Here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(VS.71).aspx) on MSDN of using a calling convention inside a function pointer typedef.

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI * CM_Open_DevNode_Key)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PHKEY, DWORD);
```

This should compile without problem.

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer must have information about the calling convention used by the function. If you're pointing to a function that uses the __cdecl calling convention, you must use a __cdecl function pointer. If you're pointing to a function that uses the __stdcall calling convention, you must use a __stdcall function pointer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: I believe function signature typedefs should *never* be expressed as **pointer** typedefs.

If you had defined CM_Open_DevNode_Key to be non-pointer, any header declaration of a function which is to follow this callback signature could simply have been written as

CM_Open_DevNode_Key myFunc;

rather than an overly verbose / **error-prone**

DWORD WINAPI myFunc(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PHKEY, DWORD);

This would allow for much simpler code and much more specific match-up of function signatures, if needed.

Not to mention that pointer typedefs are evil in general since they dis-allow specifying constness of the *content* being pointed to (infamous example: "const PCHAR" vs. the properly evaluated "const CHAR *").