# Compiling code that uses calling conventions via node-gyp on Windows MS/VS

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, node-gyp

Stating upfront, I'm not a Windows programmer.

I am trying to develop a Node extension, which is working fine on macOS, but on Windows I need to include a header with this definition:

```
typedef DWORD WINAPI (*CM_Open_DevNode_Key)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, ::PHKEY, DWORD);
```

I understand that `WINAPI` is a `#define` for `__stdcall`, which is a calling convention on win32.

The line doesn't compile with MSVS 2017: `winportfactory.h(54): error C2059: syntax error: '('` because of `__stdcall`.

I *think* I have MSVS set for win32. I have called `npm config set arch ia32` and my `binding.gyp` looks like this:

```
"defines": [
  "__WIN32__"  # Needed to include the right subheader
],
"msvs_configuration_platform": "win32",
"msvs_settings": {
  "VCCLCompilerTool": {
    "AdditionalOptions": [
      "/EHsc",
      "/std:c++17"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the complete compiler invocation:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x86\CL.exe /c /I"C:\Users\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\include\node" /I"C:\Use
  rs\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\src" /I"C:\Users\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\deps\openssl\config" /I"C:\Users\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\deps\openssl\openssl\include" /I"C:\Users\danni\.
  node-gyp\10.15.1\deps\uv\include" /I"C:\Users\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\deps\zlib" /I"C:\Users\danni\.node-gyp\10.15.1\deps\v8\include" /I..\src /I..\extern\bossa\src /I..\node
  _modules\nan /I..\src\compat /Z7 /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /MP /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy /GL /D NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=bossa /D USING_UV_SHARED=1 /D USING_V8_SHARED=1 /D
   V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1 /D WIN32 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 /D VERSION=bossajs /D __WIN32__ /D BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION /
  D _WINDLL /GF /Gm- /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR- /Fo"Release\obj\bossa\\" /Fd"Release\obj\bossa\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4800
  /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4244 /wd4267 /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue /EHsc /std:c++17 ..\src\index.cc ..\src\bossajs.cc ..\src\observer.cc ..\src\connectworker.cc MORE_FILES "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.cc"
  index.cc
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the reason it fails is not because they're turned off or some config issue, but because MSVC disagrees on the order of the tokens.

It needs to be:

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *CM_Open_DevNode_Key)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, ::PHKEY, DWORD);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297106/4391298) has more details.